# Access screens with applications' icons

Tags: android

After phone repair I lost all the applications and had to re-arrange "Applications" screens for 3 hours according to screenshots. That was a wasted time.

So, I want to write an Android application to back up the contents of screens which appear when one taps "Applications" icon. (Samsung Kies does not provide such functionality).

I would like to back up the icons placements and their parent folders.

Is there some way to access this information on an unrooted phone?

I have TouchWiz 4 shell on Samsung Galaxy SII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to access this information on an unrooted phone?

Assuming that by "'Applications' screens", you mean the home screen, then no, you cannot access this information on an unrooted phone, unless you are the author of the home screen.

Comment: I distinguish Home screen which is displayed by default and which I can customize, and screen which contains icons of all installed applications whether I want to see them or not. I'm talking about last one.

Comment: @Paul: That is a feature of the home screen. Most home screens do not have an API to allow arbitrary other apps to import and export data.